Calculate proportions by category and create histogram in ggplot
I have some data where I am hoping to calculate the proportion/percentage who experienced each of the hma variables, both overall and broken down by the respective "subgroups" within the category column.
My end goal is to produce a figure like the one below. I've been previously just calculating the proportions manually one by one and then creating a new dataframe but there must be a more efficient way.
Data:
d <- structure(list(hma1_binary = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "NA", "0", "1", "NA", "1", "1"), hma2_binary = c("0", 
"0", "0", "1", "NA", "0", "1", "NA", "0", "1", "NA", "0", "1", 
"1", "1"), hma3_binary = c("1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "NA", "0", "1", "NA", "1", "0", "0"), hma4_binary = c("1", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "NA", "1", "1", "NA", "0", 
"0", "1"), race = c("White", "White", "Black", "Black", "White", 
"Hispanic", "White", "White", "Hispanic", "White", "Black", "White", 
"White", "Black", "White"), parent_welfare = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1), parent_dropout = c(1, 0, 
1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1), parent_dropout = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))


Update: Here's how I think the resulting dataframe would ideally be organized:



Category
hma1
hma2
hma3
hma4




Total sample
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


White
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


Black
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


Hispanic
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


Parent welfare
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


Parent not welfare
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


Parent dropout HS
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion


Parent grad hs
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion
Proportion




Updated
You could do something like this
nrows_d <- nrow(d)
d_long <-d |> mutate(welfare = ifelse(parent_welfare == 1, "Welfare", "Not welfare"),
            grad = ifelse(parent_dropout...8 == 1, "Drop out", "Graduates")) |>
      pivot_longer(values_to = "value",
                  names_to = "variable",
                  cols = c(race, welfare, grad))|>
     group_by(variable, value) |>
     summarize(n = n(),
          proportion_1 = sum(hma1_binary == 1)/n,
          proportion_2 = sum(hma2_binary == 1)/n,
          proportion_3 = sum(hma3_binary == 1)/n,
          proportion_4 = sum(hma4_binary == 1)/n) |>
     ungroup() |>
     add_row(variable = "Total", value = "all",
             n = nrows_d, 
    proportion_1 = sum(d$hma1_binary ==1) /nrows_d,
     proportion_2 = sum(d$hma2_binary ==1) /nrows_d,
     proportion_3 = sum(d$hma3_binary ==1) /nrows_d,
     proportion_4 = sum(d$hma4_binary ==1) /nrows_d
)

Which will give you a data frame with the proportions and labels.  Then use geom_cols() to make the graph.  You can filter out the NAs if you want.
|variable |value       |  n| proportion_1| proportion_2| proportion_3| proportion_4|
|:--------|:-----------|--:|------------:|------------:|------------:|------------:|
|grad     |Drop out    |  8|    0.6250000|    0.3750000|    0.3750000|    0.2500000|
|grad     |Graduates   |  5|    0.4000000|    0.6000000|    0.4000000|    0.2000000|
|grad     |NA          |  2|    0.0000000|    0.0000000|    0.5000000|    0.5000000|
|race     |Black       |  4|    0.7500000|    0.5000000|    0.2500000|    0.2500000|
|race     |Hispanic    |  2|    0.5000000|    0.0000000|    0.0000000|    0.0000000|
|race     |White       |  9|    0.3333333|    0.4444444|    0.5555556|    0.3333333|
|welfare  |Not welfare |  6|    0.3333333|    0.1666667|    0.6666667|    0.3333333|
|welfare  |Welfare     |  7|    0.7142857|    0.5714286|    0.0000000|    0.2857143|
|welfare  |NA          |  2|    0.0000000|    0.5000000|    1.0000000|    0.0000000|
|Total    |all         | 15|    0.4666667|    0.4000000|    0.4000000|    0.2666667|


Add round etc. as desired.

Sorry if I wasn't clear--I think the resulting data frame from your code gives me what proportion of the sample is White, Black, Hispanic, etc. What I'm looking for is a data frame that tells me what proportion of White people experienced hma1, what proportion of White people experienced hma2, and so on for each hma variable and each subcategory of race, welfare, and graduation status. So in the resulting data frame there should be a bunch of columns for each h3ma variable.

Isn't that the first column? What does Total represent?

Total would refer to the Total/full sample--what proportion of everyone experienced hma1, hma2, etc. The updated code throws an error (unexpected ,) as well.

I updated my post to show how (I think) the final dataframe would look.
